Set scale of ploted map
I would like plot a map, using cartopy, where scale will be fixed to 1:10000.
I can't find a direct way of setting the scale, and only thing what came to my mind is to set the figsize and proper extent. Unfortunately, matplotlib is adding the margins, which I can not get rid of.
What would be the best way to render cartopy in desired scale?
